# Dynamic logout and login path for fosuserbundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I have an application built in symfony 2.3 and FOSUserBundle for authenticating its users.
This application serves multiple users based on urls, pages looks like this /urlidentifier/login. This urlidentifier is a variable and it look for a [0-9A-Za-z] + to fill that slot.

FOSUserBundle config params like Login check path and logout path are saved and cached to a file (Symfony frozen parameter).For a single website user are easily authenticated with prefixing the FOSUserBundle parameters as well as Routing.
The real issue occur when the user are switch through multiple url (super privileges)

Scenario

When a super admin is logged and authenticated via urlidentifier1/login. He could switch himself to another website without logging out. Now the url changes from urlidentifier1/index to urlidentifier2/index, he would be logged in, But when he tries to logout, The parameters like logout path would be urlidentifier1/logout. When logout is triggered we will get an error like

"You must configure the logout path to be handled by the firewall using form_login in your security firewall configuration...”

How can I make the backend use such dynamic URLs?

Comment: Have similar problem. Without FOSUserBundle even the login redirect  (upon hitting protected area) doesn't work.